# Question regarding how to automate a process

Tags: javascript, python, linux

Long story short, I am trying to figure out a way in which I can automate a process in which requires me to click within a window to end a recording when the screen turns blue. I wanted to know if there is a specific name for this type of listening process in coding. If somebody could help me figure this out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you want to achieve, but I did my best.

You can do something like this (code should be easy to understand):

1) make a screenshot (50x50 pixels will be enough) of the "blue area".

2) save it with the name area.png to the folder from where you will be running this program

3) run the program

4) click on the stop button when asked - if the stop button is not visible just click the area where it will appear (it's just to save the coordinates)

```
import pyautogui
import time
import mouse

blue_xy = False

print('click on the place, where is/or will be the stop button')
mouse.wait(button='left', target_types=('down', 'double'))
stop_button_xy = mouse.get_position()
print('coordinates of stop button are:')
print(stop_button_xy)

while not blue_xy:
    blue_xy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('area.png')
    time.sleep(2)

print("found area on the screen")
print("clicking the stop_button_xy coordinates")
mouse.move(stop_button_xy[0], stop_button_xy[1])
mouse.click()
```

In fact pyautogui module would be sufficient for this task.
Time was also optional.

You can also do it in the pixel data detecion way using coordinates (to avoid doing screenshot).

```
blue_pixel_data = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
```

But in this case I think making the screenshot of the area is better, because when you will be recording something, there is a chance in exact the same coordinates might appear pixel with the same data as in the "blue" screen.

You can also make a screenshot of the specific area to avoid the "one-pixel problem" and making screenshot before running:

```
area_screen = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, width, height))
```

When you combine it with `mouse.get_position()` to get the x and y coordinate, you can automate the process even better.

If you are sure the window size (stop button size to be more specific) will not change, you can also make a screenshot of the button. And when program will finish:

```
blue_xy = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('area.png')
```

You can detect the stop button position and save it coordinates by using the same function. The problem is the image must be exactly the same size it will appear on the screen, so I'm not sure if it would be a good idea in this case.